# Adding xbreaks to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hello I have generated the following:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
 library(ggplot2,quietly=TRUE)
 args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
 data <-read.table(args[1],header=T,sep="\t")
 pdf(args[2])
 p1 <- ggplot( data,aes(x=Mutation,y=difference) ) +
 geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(position),stat="identity"),position="dodge") +
 geom_errorbar(aes(y=difference, ymin=difference-difference_std,   ymax=difference+difference_std )) +
 theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
 ylab(expression(Delta*"Energy (Design - Wild Type)" )) +
 xlab( "Mutation" ) +
 ylim(-2.5,2.5) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size=9,hjust=1))+
 opts(legend.position="none")+
 ggtitle(expression("PG9 Mutational Analysis"))
 p1
 dev.off()
```

As you can see I've sort of grouped the positions using the fill layer so you can group them together. Ideally though I would like to put a break in the xbreak when the position changes instead of grouping them by the color.

So it would go like orange bar, orange bar, break, green bar, break, cyan bar, break, etc...

*EDIT:

Here is what the data from an input table looks like:

```
position           Mutation       difference    difference_std
97             R97L             -0.3174848488298787 0.2867477631591484
97             R97N              0.5333956571765566 0.35232170408577224
99             A99H             -0.2294999853769939 0.24017957128601522
99             A99S             -0.45171049187057877    0.0013816966425459903
101            G101S             0.5315110947026147 0.08483810927415139
102            P102S            -0.04872141488960846    0.02890820273131048
103            D103Y             0.6692000007629395 0.07312815307204293
....
```

So all the positions would be grouped together with a break on either side.
I hope I'm making sense. Is there an easy way to do this?

J

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to have the x values ordered by position and (additional?) axis breaks for position? Or do you want to facet the plot? Maybe you could provide a mock-up.

Comment: And please also provide sample data for testing. Btw, it seems like you should update ggplot2. `opts` has been deprecated quite a few versions ago.

Comment: The easiest way to think of it is a break when the color changes. So A99H and A99S would go together and then a break. (The 99 is the position number which I filled by). N109F,N109L,N109H,N109 would be grouped together and have a break on either side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use faceting (used sample data from question). To get new variable for the faceting, first, order your data frame according to `Mutation`. Then add new column `pos2` where using `cumsum()` and `diff()` according to column `position` sequence of numbers is added (idea of @agstudy).

```
df2<-df[order(df$Mutation),]
df2$pos2<-cumsum(c(0,diff(df2$position)) != 0)
df2
  position Mutation  difference difference_std pos2
3       99     A99H -0.22949999    0.240179571    0
4       99     A99S -0.45171049    0.001381697    0
7      103    D103Y  0.66920000    0.073128153    1
5      101    G101S  0.53151109    0.084838109    2
6      102    P102S -0.04872141    0.028908203    3
1       97     R97L -0.31748485    0.286747763    4
2       97     R97N  0.53339566    0.352321704    4
```

Now use new column `pos2` for facetting. With `theme()` and `strip.text=` and `strip.background=` you can remove strip texts and grey background.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=Mutation,y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(position),
                   stat="identity"),position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=difference, ymin=difference-difference_std,  
                   ymax=difference+difference_std )) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  ylim(-2.5,2.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size=9,hjust=1))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(strip.text=element_blank(),
        strip.background=element_blank())+
  facet_grid(.~pos2,scales="free_x",space="free_x")
```

[image]

### UPDATE - empty levels

Other possibility is to use `scale_x_discrete()` and argument `limits=` and add empty levels in places where you need space between bars (actual levels). Problem with this approach is that you need to add those levels manually.

For example used the same data as in previous example (ordered question data).

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=Mutation,y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(position),
           stat="identity"),position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=difference, ymin=difference-difference_std, 
            ymax=difference+difference_std )) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  ylim(-2.5,2.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size=9,hjust=1))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("A99H", "A99S","", "D103Y","","G101S",
                             "","P102S","","R97L", "R97N"))
```

[image]

Comment: +1! for the use of `facet_grid` with `facet_grid(.~group,scales="free_x")` but might I suggest something like `df2$pos2 <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$position)) != 0)` to create the new group variable?

Comment: @agstudy Thank you - make the new variable was the hardest task for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first to create a new variable that group the labels.

```
 dat$group <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$position)) != 0)

  Mutation  difference position group
20    0wYpO  0.93746859        4     0
17    63L00 -0.57833783        4     0
3     6hfEp -1.01620448        3     1
1     FvAz4  0.09496127        2     2
8     ghNTj -1.10180158        3     3
14    GxYzD  0.41997924        3     3
```

Then I don't think it will be an easy way to add a gap to your plot. But You can create a barplot by group and add the genes names with geom_text. here a first version, **I hope that someone more experienced with ggplot2 can help to adjust the texts in the middle**

```
ggplot( dat,aes(x=factor(group),y=difference) ) +
  geom_bar( width=.75,aes(fill=as.factor(Mutation)),stat="identity",
            position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Mutation),position=position_dodge(height=0.9),angle=90)+
  theme_bw() + 
  opts(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

PS: The code below can be used to generate data:

```
N <- 21
Mutation <- replicate(N,paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                    5, replace=TRUE),
                             collapse=""))


difference <- rnorm(N)
position <- c(4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2,
              5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 
              5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2)
difference_std <- sd(difference)

dat <- data.frame(Mutation,difference)
dat <- dat[order(dat$Mutation),]
dat$position <- position
dat$group <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$position)) != 0)
```